# Multisite error when adding a user: already a member of this site

Tags: multisite, user-roles

I have a strange problem when adding users to a new site on the network. The user is already registered on some other part of the site, but won't be added to the new site as the error 'That user is already a member of this site' appears. The strange thing is I don't see the member in the members list.

Anyone can help me out?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: They're likely to be 'pending' confirmation, there's a plugin that will show pending users in the network admin

Comment: They are not pending.. used a plugin and their not on the pending list..

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround, remove the user via PHPmyadmin, found in wp_user (find ID of user) and wp_usermeta (find meta info of user). Remove wp_capablities and wp_user_level from wp_usermeta and add the user again to your site via the WP backend. Somehow this reimported the user again and shows up in the user list this time. .

Answer (score 0):

I found that adding a temp "Super Admin" account and using it to remove and re-add in the account that was having the issue worked. I then removed the temp admin account once I tested it out.

It is doing the same process as the suggested editing the database via phpmyadmin, but safer, perhaps.